# parse_str from client ip address

Tags: php

In this [webpage](http://index.mediadirect.ro/getUrl?file=dw&authResponse=1) is a code that gives a different token for each ip address that access the page.

in this other page [test.php?id=token](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/test.php?id=token) I have this code running

```
<?php 
  $Text=file_get_contents("http://indexe.medwaddrect.ro/getUtel?fil=dw&authore=1");
  if(isset($_GET["id"])){
     $id = $_GET["id"];
     parse_str($Text,$data);
     echo $data[$id];
  } else {
     echo "";
  }

?>
```

the result is

> 7e9da50ab5ce7567c986228c1ad6ba3b75771b8bf15a669454b937eb

the problem is that the ip is the same is the ip of the server.

the ip is 7e9da50ab5ce7567c986228c1ad6ba3b  ***75771b8b***  f15a669454b937eb

I need every user that accest test.php?id=token to get a different number ip from ther own ip address.

note that if you enter on [webpage](http://index.mediadirect.ro/getUrl?file=dw&authResponse=1) you have another ip Number.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the server itself supports that you send it a custom IP, you're not very lucky. JavaScript (i.e., AJAX) would be the way, but this is the server's HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 23:31:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 140
Connection: keep-alive
```

So, no [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) for you. Also, adding `&jsonp=parseResponse` to the URL doesn't do anything, so I'd say no [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) either. Without the cooperation of the server, you cannot do this (and I have a feeling that you shouldn't).